# pushing docker image to dockerhub

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I ve created my own docker file ( that runs a shell script which prints "helloworld").
The image is "hellodocker" and the tag is "mytag"
I now have:

```
bash-3.2$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                   IMAGE ID            CREATED                 VIRTUAL SIZE
hellodocker         mytag                 3514c8dc11a8        39 minutes ago      2.433 MB
busybox             buildroot-2013.08.1   d200959a3e91        10 weeks ago        2.489 MB
busybox             ubuntu-14.04          37fca75d01ff        10 weeks ago        5.609 MB
busybox             ubuntu-12.04          fd5373b3d938        10 weeks ago        5.455 MB
busybox             buildroot-2014.02     a9eb17255234        10 weeks ago        2.433 MB
busybox             latest                a9eb17255234        10 weeks ago        2.433 MB

docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS               NAMES
97c29510069e        hellodocker:mytag           /bin/sh -c /Users/in   33 minutes ago                  Exited (127) 26 minutes ago                       happy_pasteur       
8d04a1385c24        hellodocker:mytag           /bin/sh -c /Users/in   37 minutes ago      Exited (127) 30 minutes ago                       mad_bell            
8998d61c0513        hellodocker:mytag           /bin/sh -c /Users/in   37 minutes ago      Exited (127) 30 minutes ago                       boring_thompson         
64314c304a29        hellodocker:mytag           /bin/sh -c /Users/in   37 minutes ago      Exited (127) 31 minutes ago                       sad_wilson          
8bc20e0555b8        hellodocker:mytag           /bin/sh -c /Users/in   38 minutes ago      Exited (127) 31 minutes ago                       sleepy_mayer        
97664a4ba870        hellodocker:mytag           .                      38 minutes ago                                                        kickass_poincare    
8bb752631cb6        busybox:buildroot-2014.02   /bin/echo Hello Doct   18 hours ago        Exited (0) 18 hours ago                           dreamy_kowalevski   
6aa66b55ca94        busybox:buildroot-2014.02   bash-3.2$ sudo docke   18 hours ago                                                          ecstatic_lovelace   
2cc657f65342        busybox:buildroot-2014.02   /bin/echo Hello Dock   18 hours ago        Exited (0) 18 hours ago                           dreamy_poincare
```

How do I push the docker image to dockerhub? I use `docker push <myuserid>/hellodocker`.  This gives a 'no such id` error.  What am I missing?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have an account on `Docker Hub`...and you're logged in?

Comment: Yes I do and yes, I am logged in

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You either need to tag it as `<myuser>/hellodocker` when you build it, e.g.

```
docker build -t <myuser>/hellodocker:mytag .
```

or create a new tag tied to the same image, i.e.

```
docker tag hellodocker:mytag <myuser>/hellodocker:mytag
```

Comment: very nice, this was bit confusing for me :-)

Comment: And don't forget the period at the end of the first line! (as @frvi has documented)

Answer (score 9):

If you want `hellodocker` repository under `myuserid` namespace, you have to first tag your local `hellodocker` to `myuserid`like:

> docker tag hellodocker myuserid/hellodocker

And then push this `myuserid/hellodocker` repository to hub like:

> docker push myuserid/hellodocker

Answer (score 1):

First go to your Docker Hub account and make the repo. Here is a screenshot of my Docker Hub account:
[image]

From the pic, you can see my repo is “chuangg”

**HOW TO UPLOAD YOUR DOCKER IMAGE ONTO DOCKER HUB**

**Method #1= Pushing your image through the command line (cli)**

1) `docker commit <container ID> <repo name>/<Name you want to give the image>`

Yes, I think it has to be the container ID. It probably cannot be the image ID.

For example= `docker commit 99e078826312 chuangg/gene_commited_image`

2) `docker run -it chaung/gene_commited_image`

3) `docker login --username=<user username> --email=<user email address>`

For example= `docker login --username=chuangg --email=gc.genechaung@gmail.com`

Yes, you have to login first. Logout using “docker logout”

4) `docker push chuangg/gene_commited_image`

**Method #2= Pushing your image using pom.xml and command line.**

Note, I used a Maven Profile called “build-docker”. If you don’t want to use a profile, just remove the `<profiles>, <profile>, and <id>build-docker</id>` elements.

Inside the parent pom.xml:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>build-docker</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                        <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.18.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <images>
                                <image>
                                    <name>chuangg/gene_project</name>
                                    <alias>${docker.container.name}</alias>
                                    <!-- Configure build settings -->
                                    <build>
                                        <dockerFileDir>${project.basedir}\src\docker\vending_machine_emulator</dockerFileDir>
                                        <assembly>
                                            <inline>
                                                <fileSets>
                                                    <fileSet>
                                                        <directory>${project.basedir}\target</directory>
                                                        <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
                                                        <includes>
                                                            <include>*.jar</include>
                                                        </includes>
                                                    </fileSet>
                                                </fileSets>
                                            </inline>
                                        </assembly>
                                    </build>
                                </image>
                            </images>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>docker:build</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Docker Terminal Command to deploy the Docker Image (from the directory where your pom.xml is located)= `mvn clean deploy -Pbuild-docker docker:push`

For those of you not using a Maven Profile, the command would simply be `mvn clean deploy docker:push`

Note, the difference between Method #2 and #3 is that Method #3 has an extra `<execution>` for the deployment.

**Method #3= Using Maven to automatically deploy to Docker Hub**

Add this stuff to your parent pom.xml:

```
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>gene</id>
            <name>chuangg</name>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
            <layout>legacy</layout>
            <url>https://index.docker.io/v1/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>build-docker</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                        <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.18.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <images>
                                <image>
                                    <name>chuangg/gene_project1</name>
                                    <alias>${docker.container.name}</alias>
                                    <!-- Configure build settings -->
                                    <build>
                                        <dockerFileDir>${project.basedir}\src\docker\vending_machine_emulator</dockerFileDir>
                                        <assembly>
                                            <inline>
                                                <fileSets>
                                                    <fileSet>
                                                        <directory>${project.basedir}\target</directory>
                                                        <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
                                                        <includes>
                                                            <include>*.jar</include>
                                                        </includes>
                                                    </fileSet>
                                                </fileSets>
                                            </inline>
                                        </assembly>
                                    </build>
                                </image>
                            </images>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>docker:build</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>docker:push</id>
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>push</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>

                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Go to C:\Users\Gene.docker\ directory and add this to your config.json file:
[image]

Now in your Docker Quickstart Terminal type= `mvn clean install -Pbuild-docker`

For those of you not using a Profile, just type `mvn clean install`

Here is a screenshot of what it will look like if it works:
[image]

Here is my full pom.xml and a screenshot of my directory structure:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.gene.app</groupId>
<artifactId>VendingMachineDockerMavenPlugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Maven Quick Start Archetype</name>
<url>www.gene.com</url>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.gene.sample.Customer_View</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>

                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>gene</id>
        <name>chuangg</name>
        <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
        <layout>legacy</layout>
        <url>https://index.docker.io/v1/</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>


<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>build-docker</id>
        <properties>
            <java.docker.version>1.8.0</java.docker.version>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.18.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <images>
                            <image>
                                <name>chuangg/gene_project1</name>
                                <alias>${docker.container.name}</alias>
                                <!-- Configure build settings -->
                                <build>
                                    <dockerFileDir>${project.basedir}\src\docker\vending_machine_emulator</dockerFileDir>
                                    <assembly>
                                        <inline>
                                            <fileSets>
                                                <fileSet>
                                                    <directory>${project.basedir}\target</directory>
                                                    <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
                                                    <includes>
                                                        <include>*.jar</include>
                                                    </includes>
                                                </fileSet>
                                            </fileSets>
                                        </inline>
                                    </assembly>
                                </build>
                            </image>
                        </images>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>docker:build</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>build</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>docker:push</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>push</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>

                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Here is my Eclipse Directory: 
[image]

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8

MAINTAINER Gene Chuang
RUN echo Running Dockerfile in src/docker/vending_machine_emulator/Dockerfile directory

ADD maven/VendingMachineDockerMavenPlugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /bullshitDirectory/gene-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 

CMD ["java", "-classpath", "/bullshitDirectory/gene-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar", "com/gene/sample/Customer_View" ]
```

Common Error #1:
[image]

Solution for Error #1= Do not sync the `<execution>` with maven deploy phase because then maven tries to deploy the image 2x and puts a timestamp on the jar. That’s why I used `<phase>install</phase>`.