# docker pull fails (not found) yet "number of pulls" increases

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I am running docker on CentOS 7 following the official documentation from https://docs.docker.com

When I try to pull a demo image I just created, I got this error:

`FATA[0013] Repository not found`

[image: the error]

The strange thing is that the "Number of Pulls" increases every time I try to pull it. As if every pull is successful.

[image: number of pulls]

Every time I get this same error: `FATA[0013] Repository not found`

So what should I do now?

**Lastest Update:** Problem solved. Thanks to Jerry Baker, one of the Docker Staff.

Please refer to https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-find-or-pull-public-repos-on-docker-hub/1806/6

---

UPDATE: I am not running docker under a http_proxy.

UPDATE 2: @user2915097 After I run `docker events`:

[image]

UPDATE 3:

My repo was not even found by `docker search`:

[image]

UPDATE 4:

`docker push` failed, too.  I've already logged in (by `docker login`).

[image]

Comment: see what `docker events` says when you do a `docker pull`

Comment: Well, it just got stuck.  (See my update2.)

Comment: maybe your wing27/centos-web-dev is not "correctly" built (this would be a bug in the Docker hub)

Comment: @user2915097 thanks for your reply. But how can I "correctly" build a image? The repository in my question is empty(created from docker hub).

Comment: you should check your repository, and contact the people dealing with the docker hub, got to IRC first

Answer (score 0):

`docker pull wings27/centos-web-dev` is not working because it does not have the 'latest' tag. It tries to pull the 'latest' tag by default if you do not provide any tag in your pull command.

[image]

Comment: Then how can I add a tag?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388684/pushing-docker-image-to-dockerhub

Comment: If you want to test, upload an image to docker hub and remove the latest tag from docker hub, you can recreate the same error/problem that you are facing.

Comment: See my UPDATE 4 , please.

Comment: Check this link: https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-push-error-fata-0001-respository-does-not-exist/1309/8, What is your docker version ? You might want to update it if not updated.

Comment: I am using a 1.6.0 version, which is newly install using yum.   In fact, it seems that I can't even find my repo on docker hub. https://registry.hub.docker.com/search?q=centos-web-dev

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79833/discussion-between-wings-and-chandan-nayak).

Answer (score 0):

Login to your docker account before accessing private repos

```
docker login
```

Answer (score 0):

If it still helps, short answer

```
docker login
docker tag <image_id> wings27/centos-web-dev:<your-tag>
docker pull wings27/centos-web-dev:<your-tag>
```